# Is it posible to add contact form on single product page in woocomerce plugin wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocomerce wordpress plugin. I dont use checking and carts features, just want use woocomerce as catalog with prices. So when user see a product I'd like that he can contact us about that product. Is it posible to add contact form on single product page in woocomerce plugin wordpress?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. . . Check: [ask] . . . .

Comment: I wish you a very simple and better idea. Make a contact-us hyper-link and pass the query-string (product_id for example) to the contact us page. Recognize the query-string on contact page. Better if you first rephrase your query

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible with Product Enquiry Form plugin:
http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-enquiry-form/

it adds a tab in the product page with enquiry form